# Alfresco share AMP structure, pack an external JS library without fail to compile yuicompressor

Tags: javascript, alfresco, alfresco-share

I have Alfresco Community 5.2 and a custom JS library to bundle together in a single amp file because I need to use that library inside share.

I tried to put it under `shareamp\web\js\`, like in the picture, but I can't compile the project because of a YUICompressor minify error, probably the JS library is too recent and not compatible with YUICompressor.

[image: lib position]

The error is the following

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:yuicompressor-maven-plugin:1.5.1:compress (compress-js) on project MyProjectShare: Execution compress-js of goal net.alchim31.maven:yuicompressor-maven-plugin:1.5.1:compress failed: Compilation produced 3 syntax errors. -> [Help 1]
```

I also tried to put it under the `META-INF\resources` folder but it doesn't work. I can compile the project and create the .amp file, but the library is not present inside the amp, like it has been ignored.

[image: lib position #2]

Obviously I can't change or remove the library, neither I can make it ES5 compatible with an external tool like babel.js.

Where is the correct place to put the JS library? Is it possible to disable yuicompressor also for prduction? (and it is correct?), Can I configure maven to put the library back in the amp in the `<build>` section (and how if it is correct?)

Thanks to all.

**PS.** I also would like to know if this problem I'm facing is caused by a wrong approach to alfresco/share extension, and, if so, how should be the best practice.

Comment: Are you allowed to skip the minification ? If so, exclude the YUI compression for that particular JS ?

Comment: Yes, I'm allowed, because the library is alredy minified by the way, How do I do that?

Comment: Are you using Ant script or maven script to create the amp ?

Comment: Maven, the pom is inherited from `alfresco-sdk-parent 2.2.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to workaround the problem adding the resources during maven install, that is, amp creation.

I placed the JS library under `WEB-INF` folder, as explained in the question, so basically alfresco ignores them at compile time and they will not get compressed/minified by YUICompressor. During validate phase of the maven install process, those files are being copied inside the correct js path.

All seems to work as espected.

I configured maven-resources-plugin, here is the code

```
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
        <execution>
        <id>copy-resources</id>
        <!-- here the phase you need -->
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/amp/web/BNextScanShare/js/DynamicWebTWAIN/</outputDirectory>
            <resources>          
                <resource>
                    <directory>/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/DynamicWebTWAIN</directory>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
            </resources>              
        </configuration>            
    </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Is that worked as you expected ? If so, please share the details, how you skipped the minify option ?

Comment: I did not skipped minify option, I preferred to add those files during the build process of the amp, so they weren't present at compile time.